# Test only if variable is not null in if statement

Tags: groovy, if-statement

I have the following method where I want to test the `event.status` property only if `status` has been passed in:

```
def findEvent(String desc, String status = null, Collection events) {
        return events.find {
            it.description == desc && \\If status is not null: it.status == status
        }

        throw new Exception("Review Event Record Not Found: ${desc}")
}
```

I thought it could be done like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def findEvent(String desc, String status = null, Collection events) {
        return events.find {
            it.description == desc && (status != null ?: {it.status == status})
        }

        throw new Exception("Review Event Record Not Found: ${desc}")
}
```

Is there any way this could be done? Or do I have to go back to something like this:

```
if (status != null) {
    return events.find {
        it.description == desc && it.status == status
    }
} else if (status == null) {
    return events.find {
        it.description == desc
    }
}
```

Is there some kind of best practice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't believe the expression is sensical as it is.

Elvis means "if truthy, use the value, else use this other thing."

Your "other thing" is a closure, and the value is `status != null`, neither of which would seem to be what you want. If `status` *is* null, Elvis says `true`. If it's not, you get an extra layer of closure.

Why can't you just use:

```
(it.description == desc) && ((status == null) || (it.status == status))
```

Even if that *didn't* work, all you need is the closure to return the appropriate value, right? There's no need to create two separate `find` calls, just use an intermediate variable.

Comment: (it.description == desc) && ((status == null) || (it.status == status)) looks perfect. Ill confirm it works when I get a chance. 
Admittedly, this is the first time I'd had ever encountered the Elvis operator, so I was sort of playing in the dark. Cheers, Dave